# Quitar caracteres especiales a un string en PHP?

Tags: php, string, php7, ascii, unicode

qué tal? Veran tengo un problemita con unos strings que estan llenos de un caracter unicode.

Mi string es este:

```
$variable = "c\u0000o\u0000d\u0000e";
```

El cual posee este unicode character : \u0000
Quisiera saber cómo puedo quitarle todos estos "\u0000" y dejar mi string así:

```
$formateada = "code";
```

Es decir sin todos esos codigos "basura".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

una forma seria utilizar str_replace, indicando como primer parametro el unicode (lo que quieres quitar), como segundo una cadena vacia (lo sustituyes por vacio) y como tercero la cadena que tienes. Seria algo como:

```
$cadena_limpia = str_replace('\u0000', '', $variable);
```

Comment: gracias!!!! me solucionó el problema.

Answer (score 1):

Fijate si esta opción te sirve

```
<?php
$variable = "c\u0000o\u0000d\u0000e";

function func($s)
{
    $ret = '';
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($s); $i++)
    {
        if($s[$i] == '\\' && $s[$i+1] == 'u')
        {
            $i += 5;
        }
        else
        {
            $ret .= $s[$i];
        }
    }
    return $ret;
}
echo $variable;
echo "<br>";
echo func($variable);

?>
```

Comment: excelente! me soluciona mi problema! gracias